# What is a file "explorer.DMP"?

Tags: windows-7

Hello Super User Community:

I was wondering what is the file: "explorer.DMP ", size 573 MB (601.062.049 bytes), which appeared on my Pc, was not created by me, i don't even know what it is or what it's for. I can't open. As a user, is there any way of identifying the content?

So specifically ask:

This file probably is generated by who? S.O. Windwos? Some program, like Internet Explorer?

From the point of view of the ordinary user: what is its usefulness in Pc's? What practical use? It's just information?

If the file ".DMP"is generated almost secret (imperceptible) and inaccessible reading for the user, is only use for analysis (WinDBG) by computer experts?

considering the space they occupy on disk, can the file.DMP be considered "file-Trash", and deleted directly to recycle-bin?

Thank you very much for help.

Comment: you should zip the dmp, upload it (onedrive, dropbox), post a share link here, so that I can analyze it with the debugger to see what caused the Explorer crash.

Comment: are you interested in the cause or have you deleted the dmp file?

Answer (score 6):

DMP files are memory dump files: they contain the working memory of a process (application) that encountered a problem. Dump files are automatically created (in some circumstances) when an application crashes. In your case, explorer - the Windows shell - has crashed.

These files are useful for developers to find the cause of a crash and if possible fix the bug. For a normal user, they are just noise and can be deleted without consequences.